# Notepad++ adding text inbetween / / to the end of the line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've got a ton of lines in the same format and i would like to add the text in between the slashes to the end of the line, for example:

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"
```

would become

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"10th Century
```

I've got no problem doing this with singular line but when i try to do it all at once i run into issues.

each line looks similar to the above example, with different words in between the slashes on each line.

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"
.replace(/11th Century/g,"
```

etc

I want the text on the end of each line to be the same as the text in between the slashes on each line

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"10th Century
.replace(/11th Century/g,"11th Century
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would like to add the text in between the slashes to the end of the line

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(.*?\/)(.*?)(\/.*?)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\2\3\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"
.replace(/11th Century/g,"
```

After:

```
.replace(/10th Century/g,"10th Century
.replace(/11th Century/g,"11th Century
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)